# How is "Make Object ID" implemented in the .NET debugger?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

I would like know how this feature is implemented in VS - I understand it holds some sort of weak-reference to the object in the debugged-application's memory, but how exactly is it accomplished?

I know simply tracking the address (as in native code) wouldn't work, because the GC might move the object about, invalidating the address.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A description of it can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jmstall/object-identity-in-managed-debugging). It uses an unmanaged api.

Comment: This link is broken.